# SQL query to find the visitor together with the date time

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

My visitor log table has **id, visitor, department,vtime** fields.

```
    id  |   visitor |           Visittime    |     Department_id
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    1         1           2019-05-07 13:53:50           1 
    2         2           2019-05-07 13:56:54           1
    3         1           2019-05-07 14:54:10           3
    4         2           2019-05-08 13:54:49           1
    5         1           2019-05-08 13:58:15           1 
    6         2           2019-05-08 18:54:30           2
    7         1           2019-05-08 18:54:37           2
```

And I have already have the following index

```
CREATE INDEX Idx_VisitorLog_Visitor_VisitTime_Includes ON VisitorLog 
    (Visitor, VisitTime) INCLUDE (DepartmentId, ID)
```

From the above table 4 filters are passed from User interface, visitor 1 and visitor 2 and visiting start time and end time.

In what are the department visitor 1 and visitor 2 both together with the VisitTime difference with in 5 mins those need to be filtered

**Output shout be**

```
    id  |   visitor |           Visittime    |     Department_id
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    1         1           2019-05-07 13:53:50           1 
    2         2           2019-05-07 13:56:54           1
    4         2           2019-05-08 13:54:49           1
    5         1           2019-05-08 13:58:15           1
```

For that I had used the following query,

```
;with CTE1 AS(
Select id,visitor,Visittime,department_id from visitorlog where visitor=1
)
,CTE2 AS(
Select id,visitor,Visittime,department_id from visitorlog where visitor=2
)
select * from CTE2 V2
Inner join CTE1 V1 on V2.department_id=V1.department_id and DATEDIFF(minute,V2.Visittime,V1.Visittime)between -5 and 5**
```

The above query takes too much of time to give response. Because in my table, almost 20 million records are available

Could any one suggest the correct way for my requirement.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see what row "4" has to do with your desired results.

Comment: At least part of the answer to this question pertains to how you have your tables set up (indexes, etc)

Comment: Not sure I follow what your question is here.

Comment: As a side comment, does anyone know whether the code `WHERE DATEDIFF(minute,V2.Visittime,V1.Visittime) BETWEEN -5 and 5` is faster than `WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(minute,V2.Visittime,V1.Visittime)) <= 5`

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Now I have edited my question. sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a completely revised answer, based upon your additional information above.**

After reviewing the data file above and the results you desire, this seems like the cleanest way to provide your results.  First, we need a different index:

```
create index idx_POC_visitorlog on visitorlog
    (visitor, Department_id, Visittime) include(id);
```

With this index, we can limit the queries to only the two passed in IDs. To simulate that, I created variables to hold their values. This query returns the data you are looking for.

```
DECLARE @Visitor1 int = 1,
    @Visitor2 int = 2

;with t as (
    select Department_id,
        dateadd(minute, -5, visittime) as EarlyTime,
        dateadd(minute, 5, Visittime) as LateTime,
        id
    from visitorlog
    where visitor = @Visitor1
    ),
v as (
    select v.id, 
        t.id as tid
    from visitorlog v
    INNER JOIN t 
        ON v.visitor = @Visitor2
        AND v.Department_id = t.Department_id
        and v.Visittime BETWEEN t.EarlyTime and t.LateTime
    )
SELECT *
FROM visitorlog vl
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT v.id
    FROM v
    UNION
    SELECT v.tid
    FROM v
    )
ORDER BY visittime;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my primary need is to find the visitors visits the department together with in 5 mins.see the demo link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1fe58/1/0  .In the last 2 rows shows same visitor only  for the same department

Comment: Note that I can not verify if this is fast, faster than the existing query, or slower than the existing query. That will depend on your query. Also note that limiting the timeframe you are examining for matching visits will speed the entire process, since looking at this

Answer (score 1):

If your version of SQL Server supports the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) and [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) functions, try rewriting the query as follows:

```
with t as (
  select
    *,
    dateadd(minute, 5,
      lag(Visittime) over(partition by Department_id order by Visittime)) lag_visit_time,
    dateadd(minute, -5,
      lead(Visittime) over(partition by Department_id order by Visittime)) lead_visit_time
  from visitorlog
  where visitor in(1, 2)
)
select
  id, visitor, visittime, department_id
from t
where lag_visit_time >= Visittime or lead_visit_time <= Visittime;
```

This index is called a [POC](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/06/indexing-for-windowing-functions/).

Results:

```
+----+---------+----------------------+---------------+
| id | visitor |      visittime       | department_id |
+----+---------+----------------------+---------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2019-05-07T13:53:50Z |             1 |
|  2 |       2 | 2019-05-07T13:56:54Z |             1 |
|  4 |       2 | 2019-05-08T13:54:49Z |             1 |
|  5 |       1 | 2019-05-08T13:58:15Z |             1 |
|  6 |       2 | 2019-05-08T18:54:30Z |             2 |
|  7 |       1 | 2019-05-08T18:54:37Z |             2 |
+----+---------+----------------------+---------------+
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6df98/17).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my primary need is to find the visitors visits the department together with in 5 mins.see the link demo link 
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1fe58/1/0  .In the last 3 rows same visitor only shows –

Comment: Visits with IDs 6 and 7 show that visitors were in department 2, not 1, as for the visit with ID 5. Please explain what was done wrong?

Comment: Please check the below link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1fe58/1/0  see the last 2 rows. My primary need to view two visitors visits the same department with in 5 mins difference.